# Is it possible use foreach in parallel for all nests for a function using input from previous step in R?

Tags: r, loops, recursion, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am running some heavy simulations in R. Hence, I have been trying to parallelize my computations to speed it up. I have figured out how to use the `foreach` package to run a loop in parallel. I have also figured out how to use the same package to run nested loops in parallel. However, I don`t know how to run recursions in parallel (or even if it possible to do so). Is it possible to do it and, if so, how can I implement it in my example code below?

Below I provide an example code of what I would like to do and what I have done that actually works (my code is actually much more complicated than this and has a third loop, the code below is a simplification for clarity).

**What I would like to achieve:** Both loops are run in parallel and I can use the output from the inside loop as an input to the function it contains in the next step of the outside loop. This is shown in the code below. However, this code does not work, because it does not actually update the `next_step_data` in memory. In other words, this is as if I was inputting `data` to `my_function()` in all the four iterations of the inside loop.

```
install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(mlogit, tidyverse, foreach, doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cores=4)

next_step_data <- data

output <- foreach (j=1:1000, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {

    next_step_data <- foreach (k=1:4, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
  
      my_function(k, next_step_data)
  
    }

    next_step_data %>%
      group_by(var1, var2) %>%
      summarise(n = n()/4) %>%
      ungroup()

  }
```

**What I have managed to do:** Only the inside loop is run in parallel. That is sort of fine because `my_function()` is the most computationally intensive part of my code, but the outside loop that will runs 1000 times, so it would be great to have everything running in parallel.

```
install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(mlogit, tidyverse, foreach, doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cores=4)

next_step_data <- data

output <- foreach (j=1:1000, .combine = "rbind") %do% {

    next_step_data <- foreach (k=1:4, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
  
      my_function(k, next_step_data)
  
    }

    next_step_data %>%
      group_by(var1, var2) %>%
      summarise(n = n()/4) %>%
      ungroup()

  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean that you only got 4x speedup or do you actually know that only the inside loop is parallelized? You are using 4 cores, so the maximum speedup you can get is 4x, regardless of what is parallelized.

Comment: @GeorgeOstrouchov, I am aware that only the inside loop is parallelized and of the theoretical limits of speedup. My question is if there is a way of parallelizing the outside one too given that I have a recursion going on. My code is more complicated than this (it has three loops, I parallelized only the innermost one because I have the recursion) and going from sequential to 8 cores I got a 2x speedup.

Comment: In that case, why not parallelize only the 1000 loop, where you have the opportunity of 1000-way parallelism? Are you running on a Windows or a Unix/Mac platform?

Comment: @GeorgeOstrouchov, I am running on Linux. The heavy part of my code is within the innermost loop, that's why I decided to parallelize it. Do you think parallelizing the outside one (1000 loop) would be better?

Comment: Absolutely! You should parallelize the coarsest or outermost loop for the least overhead effect. Also, since you are on Linux, put the loop innards into a function and use `mclapply()` from the parallel package. The output is a list, which you then combine with `do.call(list, rbind)`. It is the simplest and most direct way to use all cores on any Unix platform. No need to register anything (foreach uses it under the covers).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sketch, here is an equivalent mclapply sketch:

```
library(parallel)
library(tidyverse)
## add other libs needed

outer_function <- function(i, next_step_data) {
    ns_list <- lapply(1:4, my_function, next_step_data = next_step_data)
    next_step_data <- do.call(rbind, ns_list)

    next_step_data %>%
      group_by(var1, var2) %>%
      summarise(n = n()/4) %>%
      ungroup()
}

output <- mclapply(1:1000, outer_function, next_step_data = data, mc.cores = 4)
output <- do.call(rbind, output)
```

Assumes `my_function(k, next_step_data)` has parameters as stated. Adjust mc.cores to your available cores.

`mclapply` uses the Unix `fork` which is copy-on-write, meaning that memory is shared (no duplication) until you change something in that memory and then only the pages written-to are copied.